# creating float point colors

Tags: python, css, python-3.x

I want to to draw a pixel with float point color e.g rgb(173.373, 216, 230)
I tried using Pillow Image and Imagecolor but without success

My main Target is to be able to both read and write float point colors off images.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageColor

im = Image.new("RGB", (32, 32), ImageColor.getrgb("rgb(173.373, 216, 230)"))

im.save('simplePixel.png')
```

But i get the following error:

```
raise ValueError("unknown color specifier: %r" % color)
ValueError: unknown color specifier: 'rgb(173.373, 216, 230)'
```

Comment: As far as know there is no such "granular" level of color. You are limited to the16,777,216 combinations...the number of colors available is NOT infinite.

Comment: you are right but how can i do float point colors,please have a look here w3schools.com/colors/tryit.asp?filename=trycolors_rgb you can use float point colors it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paulie_D said, there is no such "level" of color. You can't use floats in the color string.

The Documentation states:

> RGB functions, given as rgb(red, green, blue) where the color values are integers in the range 0 to 255. Alternatively, the color values can be given as three percentages (0% to 100%). For example, rgb(255,0,0) and rgb(100%,0%,0%) both specify pure red.

So these are the only options you can use.

Comment: you are right but how can i do float point colors,please have a look here https://www.w3schools.com/colors/tryit.asp?filename=trycolors_rgb you can use float point colors it works .

Comment: Why do you need floats here? As you can see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp) there are only integers allowed.

Comment: there are metadata to pictures only obtainable via float point analysis of pictures and please try playing with float point colors if you have HD screen you will notice the difference in colors

Comment: In any image file format, that should be integers internally though, except that the bit resolution may be higher than 8 bit per channel and pixel. With `numpy` you can create and handle such images, but I don't know if there are any Python modules that can save and read from RGB16 PNGs. Or whatever your desired format is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV to either load the image or convert the image from Pillow. OpenCV allows you to use floating-point colors, that way you can add decimals in RGB values. Do note that there is absolutely no point in doing this, as most monitors can only display colors in sRGB, which is 8 bits per color channel(8 for Red, 8 for Blue, 8 for Green) and only HDR monitors can even read floating-point colors. Most monitors don't even display these colors accurately, and even low-end HDR monitors have inaccurate color reproduction.

Basically, you shouldn't need to deal work with floating-point colors unless you are working with neural networks, but you can use OpenCV if you want to.